# Emit client validation attributes on certain properties but not all

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation, client-side-validation

The more I read, the more I think this is not doable, but I thought of getting the community's opinion on this before I conclude anything.

I have models like these (simplified for example purposes)

```
public class Family
{
    public Member Father { get; set; }
}

public class Member
{
    [Remote("IsUnique", "ValidatePhone")]
    [Required]
    public Phone CellPhone { get; set; }

    public Phone Phone { get; set; }
}

public class Phone
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

And a `Create` view like this:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Father.Phone)

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Father.CellPhone)
```

So I want the Cellphones to be unique and required but not the other ones.

I have tried FluentValidation as well, but ultimately it boils down to MVC's limitations.

This is not working. It doesn't emit `data-val` attributes which is not a surprise. But I cannot put those attributes on the `Phone.Number` field since not every phone needs to have this validation.

So is this doable somehow?

Comment: It wont work because `Phone` is a complex object. It would only work if your property was `[Remote("IsUnique", "ValidatePhone")] [Required] public string CellPhone { get; set; }` (and just another reason why you should be using view models)

Comment: I already noted that. I cannot use a flat view model since its not as simple as this example. If I flatten, its going to be a messy one, with 50+ properties.